# Tracking movement via ImageFeatureTracking doesn't work

Tags: image-processing

I have a series of 37 b/w microscopy photos. The whole sample shifts slightly (by ~10 pixels) from photo to photo (systematic error). See an example photo here and download two photos [pos4_0.dat](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=08804528967852852453) and [pos4_40.dat](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02161030475855538633), shifted by ~10px. Moreover, there are major intensity variations. Nevertheless, the main structure is always visible.

[image: photo]

I want to track the trajectory of some points through the photo series. Later on, I will stabilize my regions of interest. The last example in [Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFeatureTrack.html) would be excactly what I need, but ImageFeatureTrack doesn't work.

```
import = Import[#] & /@ {"pos4_0.dat", "pos4_40.dat"}
images = Image[Rescale[#]] & /@ import
ImageFeatureTrack[images]
Out[55]={{}, {}}
```

How can I improve the performance of ImageFeatureTrack or solve my problem in another way?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the images?

Comment: You could try helping it out by giving it the coordinates of the feature in the first image. It looks like it's not finding a feature to begin with.

Comment: @M.R. raw data is given as download link in the first paragraph. Does this work for you?

Comment: Your Images are 8 MB each. Perhaps you could reduce the resolution for this question ...

Comment: @N.J.Evans: I didn't succeed with that. Since the photos are gray-in-gray, no single pixel seems to be outstanding. I would like to define a whole region as feature.

Comment: [Similar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89416/30913) still unanswered but with some suggestions. [One Solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73783/30913) but operates on WRI's example data, which the image processing functions usually seem to be tailored to. [An alternative](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35531/30913) to `ImageFeatureTracking`.

Comment: For some reason the download does not work for me. Anyhow, looking at the samples in the question I would think that `FindGeometricTransform` or `ImageAlign` are better suited to this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the sample images linked in the question aren't available for download and the question is not answerable without them